# XmlSerializer auto detect type from XML when deserializing (.NET 2.0)?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

Currently, I'm using XmlSerializer to serialize different objects (.NET 2.0)

The serialized content looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InitActivityAction xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EmploymentID>1</EmploymentID>
  <DateFrom>2011-11-14T21:08:17.5893302Z</DateFrom>
</InitActivityAction>
```

XmlSerializer constructor requires Type to be specified. But I use many object types.

Is there a way to make XmlSerializer "auto-detect" required type from the XML?

Answer (score 4):

Not out of the box.

You do have options though. Here are some:

(1) You can peek at the XML using, say, XPath to get the root element name to determine the object type (or use distinct namespaces for each class).

(2) You can also use a more involved XML serializer like [this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CGEQFjAH&url=http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/deepserializer.aspx&ei=qyvxTuCIDrCOigKJ1bS9Dg&usg=AFQjCNEKIvoTY1X7kezZO1B0xiUv-aDggQ) in CodeProject which will auto-determine types from a "dictionary" - and then you can use reflection to determine which type it really is.

(3) You can also just try to deserialize the XML with each XmlSerializer for each type you have - and moving on to the next one if it fails. Not very nice.

(4) Finally, you can create a class that has a member for each of your objects and serialize it instead of each object individually, with say, an enum member to help you write code to extract the right member. Again, not a nice solution.

Notice that all of these approaches add performance costs. And they're not exactly nice options :)